# how to drag & drop buttons on Iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, netbiscuits

I am developing for Iphone by using Netbiscuits tool. I need to use drag & drop functionality on IPhone. I have found a javascript code which locates at Drag Drop Javascript Library for iPad & iPhone. However I am not able to use drag & drop functionality by usng javascript code which was given at the website. Have you ever added drag & drop functionlity to IPhone? I would be glad if you have a sample which was written on Javascript. Thank you from now for your helps.

Regards
Altaico

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at a similar problem I found some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378060/uitableview-drag-a-row-onto-another-one).

But it used objective-C and not Javascript. The idea behind it is, as you touch an object you can create an UIImageView that represents it (maybe semi-transparent like drag&drop on the desktop works), add it on the main UIView as a subview and move it around by intercepting the dragging in the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method

Comment: i have to use only javascript mate. Netbiscuits platform does not accept objective c. Here is the problem in brief: I will be glad if any of you can help me. I need to resolve this problem asap.
Has anyone tried drag & drop using Jquery in Iphone? I have tried many codes but I have no result about the drag&drop. Maybe I thought it is not possible to try it with simulator (maybe it only works with phone) Anyone has any working code or anyone knows a working jquery or javasript code (sample)? I will be glad if you can help me. I have been trying to fix that issue for 3 days but still no result.

Comment: Sorry, but as I said above, I can provide you only an objective-C workaround