# Customising UITableView reorder behaviour and animations

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'd like to customise the behaviour of my tableview when reordering. When you reorder rows I would like to be able to 'drop' one row on top of another to create a group.

I have seen other apps do this so I know that it is possible but I don't see any relevant hooks for customising this in the UITableView class reference.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Bit of help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378060/uitableview-drag-a-row-onto-another-one

Comment: Thanks John I'll take a look. Shame there is no sample code.